# Rails self referencing association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Item and I want to have a 'Recipe' which is just an Item which references many_of :items.

I have a record in the ingredients table: `(id: 1, recipe_id: 1, item_id: 2)`

I want to be able to:

`item.find(1).items` - return all the items for recipe_id: 1

`item.find(1).ingredients` - return the ingredient records where recipe_id: 1

`item.find(2).recipes` - return all the recipes for which item_id: 2

I am able to get item.find(1).items working OR item.find(2).recipes working BUT NOT BOTH... :(

MIGRATION

```
class CreateIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :ingredients do |t|
      t.references :items, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :recipe, references: :items, foreign_key: { to_table: :items }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

INGREDIENTS model

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe, class_name: 'Item'
  belongs_to :item
end
```

ITEM model

```
has_many :ingredients

has_many :items, through: :ingredients
has_many :recipes, through: :ingredients
```

Comment: what do you mean by BUT NOT BOTH?

Comment: Why do you want to have item reference itself? Why is a recipe "just an item"? Wouldn't it be easier to use a structure like the one outlined in [The `has_many :through` Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association). The `Recipe` would be "carrot cake", an `Item` would be "carrot" and one `Ingredient` would link the two. The `Ingredient` model probably also has a _quantity_ attribute (e.g. 5) meaning there are 5 carrots in the carrot cake. Queries would be straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually modeled the assocations correctly. This isn't actually a valid use case for a self-referential association.

What you actually want is to use a join table between recipies and ingredients:

```
class CreateRecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :recipe_ingredients do |t|
      t.belongs_to :recipe, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :ingredient, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.decimal :quantity
      t.string :unit # better would be to use a separate table or enum
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You can name it whatever you want. Naming it `a_bs` is just a lazy convention. This is also where you are going to want to store the quantity of the ingredients.

You then setup a many to many assocation with `has_many through:`:

```
class Recipe < Application
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < Application
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  delegate :name, to: :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < Application
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipies, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

The reason you want `has_many through:` and not `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that the later is highly limited and doesn't let you access additional columns on the join table like the quantity in this case.

You can then get just use the indirect assocations to get recipies for an ingredient or vice versa:

```
Recipe.find(1).ingredients
Ingredient.find(5).recipies
```

You can also use joins to get recipies with certain ingredients:

```
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
      .where(ingredients: { name: 'Broccoli' })

# Recipies with at least one of Broccoli, Kale and Squash
Recipe.joins(:ingredients)
      .where(ingredients: { name: ['Broccoli', 'Kale', 'Squash'] })

# Recipies with Broccoli, Kale and Squash
Recipe.left_joins(:ingredients)
      .where(ingredients: { name: ['Broccoli', 'Kale', 'Squash'] })
      .group(:id)
      .having(Ingredient.arel_table[:id].count.gteq(3))
```

If you want to write out a recipe you want to iterate across the `recipe_ingredients` assocation and not `ingredients`:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <% recipe.recipe_ingredients.each do |ri| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= ri.name %></td>
      <td><%= ri.quantity %></td>
      <td><%= ri.unit %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Addendum

If you want to create a self-referential assocation between a recipe and "sub-recipes" you can do it either as one-to-many:

```ruby
class AddParentToRecipes < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_table :recipes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :parent, null: true, 
                            foreign_key: { to_table: :recipes }
    end
  end
end

class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  belongs_to :parent,
    class_name: 'Recipe',
    optional: true
  has_many :children, 
    class_name: 'Recipe'
    foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

Or many to many:

```
class CreateRecipeComponents < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :recipe_components do |t|
      t.belongs_to :parent, null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :recipes }
      t.belongs_to :child, null: false, 
        foreign_key: { to_table: :recipes } 
    end
  end
end

class RecipeComponent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Recipe'
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Recipe'
end


class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :recipe_components_as_parent,
    class_name: 'RecipeComponent',
    foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :recipe_components_as_child,
    class_name: 'RecipeComponent',
    foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :sub_recipies,
    through: :recipe_components_as_parent,
    source: :child
  has_many :parent_recipies,
    through: :recipe_components_as_child,
    source: :parent
end
```

While having an "item" that references either a recipe or ingredient might sound like a good idea from an object oriented POV you need to remember that its not how relational databases actually work. In a relational database tables have references to other tables through foreign keys and the table which that foreign key points to is not dynamic.

While you can use a polymorphic assocation to do this remember that its a hack around how databases are actually envisioned to work.

Comment: I guess you could go either way in naming this - @Stefan has a pretty good suggestion in using `items` as the normalized table for a "type" of ingredient and then ingredient as the join table. The key point here is really that you want a many to many assocation.

Comment: thank you for you in-depth answer and explanation. I will implement this tomorrow and come back with my results :)

Comment: Hi, 
I just read through your answer but this ins't exactly what I was looking for.

The reason I wanted a Recipe to also be an Ingredient is because I want to treat them almost the same.

There are 'recipes' for parts which make up a room. e.g. a part could be a single ingredient e.g. an oven. or a recipe e.g. a wall (which would contain, multiple ingredients). (plasterboard, timber, paint etc)

I want to be able to add recipes or single ingredients to a room.

Comment: Yeah. You would still model that the same way but you would setup an additional self referential association between recipes. That would be either a one to many (a foreign key column on recipes) or many to many with an additional join table.

Comment: That would let you have for example a Pie recipe which references the Crust and Custard recipes.

Comment: While you could have an "item" reference either a recipe or an ingredient it would require you to use a polymorphic association which means no foreign keys to enforce referential integrity, crappy support for eager loading etc. I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: Thanks @max. I got it working using the above and a self referential association.